# How to create a total (SUM) calculation in a view

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

I have a view that I want to find the sum of, which is the total miles... So if the user filters on july-15 then I wanted a sum to display anywhere on the view of the total miles, in bellows example would be 10+101.. maybe 111 appears below that number.... is there a way?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new number column,create a workflow to update the new number column with the value of calculated column.Now "Sum" the number column in the view.

Comment: can you guide me through this? I am fairly new to workflows

Comment: Create a new number column in the list and name it very similar to your calculated column.Now open SharePoint Designer and create a new workflow in the list.Make the workflow start option to trigger when an item is created and also when an item is changed.Add "Update List item" from Actions(in ribbon).Click 'this list" text and click "Add".Select your number column in "Set this field" drop down and in "To this value",select the fx icon and select "Current Item" and "your calculated column name".Publish the worklfow

Comment: Running a workflow on every item update isn't the best idea for performance and concurency reasons. If you need no-code solution it may be the only way to go. Otherwise, I'd strongly reccomend rendering the sum in JS or replacing workflow with event receiver.

Comment: George is the correct? http://i58.tinypic.com/25ip10x.png    also I how do I change the workflow start option to trigger when item is created or changed

Comment: @Raymound In the workflow,you are just calculating but you are not updating any column using the calculated value.Use "Update List Item" Action to update the number column with your calculation.With what I can see,you don't require the 2nd calculation,instead use a "update List item" action and update "Total Miles" column with the variable "Calc".Regarding Workflow start options,click on "workflow Settings" in SPD ribbon,there you can see the heading "Start Options" when you can select and make the workflow to run on item creation and item update.

Comment: i made the changes from what you said, is it correct?  Thank you for your help btw. http://i61.tinypic.com/314sfo8.png

Comment: @Raymound: In "Update List Item" step,set the field as "Total Miles" and the value as "Workflow Variable:Calc". I assume "Total Miles" is the new number column created instead of the calculated column

Comment: The thing is the "Total Miles" is not displaying because it is a calculated column which is (odometer out-odometer in).... I want to find the sum of total miles

Comment: @Raymound. Create a new number column,named "TotalMiles".In "Update List Item" step,set the field as "TotalMiles" and the value as "Workflow Variable:Calc".

Comment: this is how it looks.... http://i60.tinypic.com/rurwqb.png if correct how do I run it? I saved it and published it aswell

Comment: @Raymound Super.. Now open your workflow,you should be able to see "Workflow Settings" in the ribbon.Click "workflow Settings",now you would see a heading named "Start Options",select 2nd and 3rd option and publish the workflow

Comment: I did that already, what are the next steps in my view?

Comment: Now when a item is created or modified,the workflow will update the "Total Miless" column.Now edit the view --> add "Total miless" column to the view --> In "Totals" section,select "Sum" against "Total miless"

Comment: thank you so much I realty appreciate your patience and time.

Answer (score 5):

On the *List* tab on the ribbon select *Modify View*. Scroll down and expand *Totals* section. Select *Sum* next to *Total Miles* column and save the view. You can use it together with groups and sorting.

[image: Sum]

**Calculated colum**
I've created calculated column with result type `number` and set view aggregation from code. It works fine with COUNT (which is also impossible to set from UI):

[image: Count on calculated field]

But for SUM it does not display propertly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunly the TOTAL MILE column is not displaying in the Totals format because it is a calculated field.. how should I go around that

Comment: Create a new number column,create a workflow to update the new number column with the value of calculated column.Now "Sum" the number column in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There were some tutorials on this in sharepoint 2010 times... like this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/e6c4bb8e-6162-419f-ba74-bb9f48f7fbdc/sum-in-xsltlistviewwebpart-with-sharepoint-designer-2010

Unfortunatelly it has become a lot harder in the days since sharepoint designer doesn't have preview functionality anymore.

I would probably advise you to try to achieve your goal with jQuery, but it definitly has its disadvantages.